# Copied Magento 2 website PDF Invoices not working

Tags: sales, magento2.4.3, invoice-pdf

I have copied our website over to a new hosting platform with more resources etc. I have done this lots of times before without any difficulty. Everything is working apart from Sales PDF Invoices. They download but are all corrupted and won't open. On the live website (which is still live where they do work) which I have copied from they are approx 198kb. On the destination server they are 70kb. I have checked the system and debug logs and the only that is appearing is **main.ERROR: Environment emulation nesting is not allowed. [] []** in both.

I have upgraded, compiled, deployed, flushed, set permissions, reindexed.

I have have tried everything. Help!

Comment: Could be related to PHP extension. Have you checked if your server meets the Magento requirement? https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-operations/installation-guide/prerequisites/php-settings.html?lang=en

Comment: Thanks I checked that and it all looks ok. Used php -v and php -m and everything seems to ok.